# Herança em classes

Tags: python

Tenho um desafio para criar um pequeno sistema em Python que gerencie as associações em um clube. Para isso, criei a seguinte classe:

```
class Carteira:
    def __init__(self,numero,atividade,bilhete):
        self.numero = numero
        self.atividade = atividade
        self.bilhete = bilhete

    ##SETTERS##

    def set_numero(self,numero):
        self.numero = numero
    def set_atividade(self,atividade):
        self.atividade = atividade
    def set_bilhete(self,bilhete):
        self.bilhete = bilhete

    ##GETTERS##

    def get_numero(self):
        return self.numero
    def get_atividade(self):
        return self.atividade
    def get_bilhete(self):
        return self.bilhete

class ControleClube(Carteira):
    def __init__(self, numero, atividade, bilhete):
        super().__init__(numero,atividade,bilhete)
        self.lista_de_socios = []

    ##SETTERS##
    def set_lista_de_socios(self, lista_de_socios):
        self.lista_de_socios = lista_de_socios
    ##GETTERS##
    def get_lista_de_socios(self):
        return self.lista_de_socios

    ##METODOS##
    def acrescenta_lista_socio(self, Carteira):
        self.lista_de_socios.append((self.numero, self.bilhete))

    def atualiza_lista_socios(self,Carteira):
        if (self.numero, self.bilhete) not in self.lista_de_socios:
            if self.atividade == True:
                lista_de_socios.append((self.numero, self.bilhete))
            else:
                pass
        if (self.numero, self.bilhete) in self.lista_de_socios:
            if self.atividade == False:
                lista_de_socios.remove((self.numero, self.bilhete))
        return self.lista_de_socios

carteira = Carteira(2, True, 23)
carteira.set_numero(23)
carteira.set_atividade(True)
carteira.set_bilhete(2)
lista_socios = ControleClube(2, True, 23)
lista_socios.acrescenta_lista_socio(carteira)
carteira02 = Carteira(3, True, 24)
lista_socios.acrescenta_lista_socio(carteira02)
print(lista_socios.get_lista_de_socios())
```

Entretanto, quando peço para armazenar outro sócio na lista de sócios, ele duplica os dados do primeiro sócio inscrito, e não registra o novo. O que há de errado nesse código?

Comment: Vamos por partes. 1) Por que a classe `ControleClube` herda `Carteira`? 2) Por que a classe `ControleClube` possui vários métodos que recebem um parâmetro chamado `Carteira` que não é utilizado?

Comment: Ela herda Carteira porque é uma forma de manusear os dados registrados. Carteira serve para registrar um novo sócio, e ControleClube para gerenciar eles. Não entendi porque não é necessário apresentar o parâmetro Carteira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Diovana, não esta adicionando por causa do seu método:

```
def acrescenta_lista_socio(self, Carteira):
    self.lista_de_socios.append((self.numero, self.bilhete))
```

Repare que na segunda linha você esta dando o append em self.numero e self.bilhete, ou seja, você não esta pegando os dados da Carteira nova, esta pegando dados da carteira que você já tem.
Substitua por:

```
def acrescenta_lista_socio(self, Carteira):
    self.lista_de_socios.append((Carteira.get_numero(), Carteira.get_bilhete()))
```

Comment: Nossa, nem tinha reparado nisso. Muito obrigada! :)